# BigQuery view integer column read as Json when imported in PowerBI

Tags: json, postgresql, google-bigquery, powerbi

I have created this view in BigQuery:

```
create view project.dataset.view1 as
SELECT 
     o.first
    ,o.id as theid
    ,p.id as otherid
FROM dataset.view2 as o
JOIN dataset.view3 as p on p.whatever = o.id
```

When i add the data in that view to PowerBi, the column p.id it shows as Json string with all the three columns, while it should be only an integer.
This is an example of what i see:

```
{""v"":{""f"":[{""v"":""name""},{""v"":""11""},{""v"":""9""}]}}
```

In BigQuery it just looks fine with the integer value I'm expecting.
Can somebody shed some light on this? It's driving me nuts. Thanks.

Comment: use transform as json and expand your record; Check this:
https://youtu.be/ipI6mrWLQKA?t=198

Comment: Thank you for the possible solution, but it doesn't work for me as the 3 value fields are all called "v", and when i try to expand PowerBI gets "confused" plus i would like to understand the source of the problem and avoid too many operations in PBI. PBI might not stay as our visualization and BI tool of choice too.

Comment: Maybe this article explain something:

https://www.inflexionanalytics.com/blogs/importing-unnested-data-from-bigquery-to-powerbi/

Comment: That looks like raw BigQuery API output, it must be something with the PowerBI connector that didn't parse that content. I would catalogue this as a bug.

Comment: I think this is not a nesting problem, because i only select an integer to insert in that column, not a list of values.
And also if i query that view on BigQuery, i only see an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i don't know how much of a bug vs my fault this is. i have named the 3rd column just like the view.
Not sure here if it's a good thing to do, but again, Google Data Studio and KlipFolio didn't give me that result.
Changing the column name fixed it though in PowerBI.